# Jenkins pipeline "cd" command not working, "cd" vs "dir"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I encounter an issue where `cd` is not working in a Window Node:

```
node("Window-node") {                       

    stage('unstash'){
        echo 'unstash..'

        deleteDir()                             

        unstash name: uat_stash
        unstash name: prd_stash

        bat "cd ${path}"
        bat "mkdir ${params.tag_name}"          

    }
}
```

The problem happen in `bat "cd ${path}"`, it doesn't really go to the specific path, so the `mkdir` fails.

The `path` is somewhere outside of jenkins workspace, while I am using below, it works fine:

```
dir("${path}") {
    bat "mkdir ${params.tag_name}"
}
```

I am not too sure why, but I don't prefer to use `dir` because it will create a temp folder `xxx@tmp`, but never clean up after Jenkins job finished.

Anyone know why the `cd` fails? Or, am I able to use `dir` without creating a Jenkins temp folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first command `bat "cd ${path}"` does what you expect. However, the second `bat` step does not run in the context of the previous step, so it starts from the worker node root workspace directory.

You can solve it by replacing two `bat` steps with a single multiline script, e.g.

```
node("Window-node") {

    stage('unstash'){
        echo 'unstash..'

        deleteDir()

        unstash name: uat_stash
        unstash name: prd_stash

        bat """
            cd ${path}
            mkdir ${params.tag_name} 
        """.stripIndent().trim()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Add option `/d`, in case cross driver, For example `${path}` is in `D:\`, but you current in `C:\`

2) Wrap ${path} inside `"`, in case there is space in ${path}

```
bat """ cd /d "${path}" """
```

Comment: Although Szymon solution solve my problem actually, your points are good notes as well. Thanks for highlighting the possible pitfall.